# Coordinate increment

Tags: java, 2d, coordinates

So I'm making this 2d space shoooter, and I'm trying to make my player shoot. So what I'm using is

```
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
 c.addBullet(new Bullet(p.getX(), p.getY(), this));
        System.out.println(p.getX()+ "x, y "+ p.getY());
 }
```

and for some reason it only takes the second argument into account (the getY argument) if I change it and put

```
c.addBullet(new Bullet(p.getY(), p.getX(), this));
```

the opposite happen. As I move my spaceship up, both the x and y axis increment. 
I'm using the system.out statement to make sure that there's nothing wrong with the getters and that the actual coordinates work, which they do.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

BulletClass:

```
package SpaceGame.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Bullet {
private double x;
private double y;
BufferedImage image;

public Bullet(double x, double y, Game game){
this.x=y;
this.y=y;

SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet());
image = ss.grabImage(2, 1, 32, 32);
}

public void tick(){

}

 public void render(Graphics g){
g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the code for the `Bullet` class .

Comment: Hmm, how would I go about doing that? Just edit my question and post it below?

Comment: Yes edit your question and add the code : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42783494/edit

Comment: Ah, got it! Now includes Bullet class.